# Layout replacement in android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have my layouts like below:

Layout 1 : I have a `LinearLayout`(parent - horizontal).

Layout 2 & 3: I have two more layouts(2 and 3) side by side in Layout 1.

In Layout 2 (left side), I have a couple of buttons(button 1 and button 2). What I am looking for?

Whenever I click on button1 or button2 - I want to switch the right side layout which is 3 (complete layout - not like changing `TextView` and all) ( as in the TableLayout`) between some layout 4 and layout 5.

Comment: wireframe design of your problem pls........

Comment: 1 picture ==== 1000 words. so post the problem snap.

Comment: do you have exact number of layouts to replace in layout 3 or it's indefinite?

Comment: GKR, I have separate layouts(4&5) of views to replace layout 3 ..

Comment: paresh, i want to simulate a tablayout in vertical mode... i could use fragments as such which is in 3.0.. but i have 2.2 ...

Comment: want to replace the layout 3 with layout 4 and layout 5 upon clicking button 1 and 2 respectively in layout 2....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make layout 4 & 5 children of layout3 and take a look at `ViewFlipper` to switch between the views. Or, take a look at `ViewPager` if you want to swipe between views.

You can have support for ViewPager (and other >=3.0 features, including fragments) on pre 3.0-devices using the [Android Compatibility library](http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html).

If you want fuller ActionBar support on earlier devices, you can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://www.actionbarsherlock.com) (which extends the compatibility package).